# Target android 4.1 works on previous versions?

Tags: java, android, api, target

I have a question that may seem stupid, but I have exclarecer this ...

I have an app for android that due to the use of apis had to put targeting Android 4.1.

My doubt is whether the app will work on android devices with the system below 4.1?

in my manifest file put the following

```
<uses-sdk
         android: minSdkVersion = "8"
         android: targetSdkVersion = "16" />
```

I tested on my device that has android 2.3.6 and runs normal without any bug, the same holds for other versions without presenting problems?

Answer (score 3):

### Minimum SDK Version

The minimum SDK version is the lowest API you can run your application on without causing problems.

> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.
>
> -- [`<uses-sdk>` Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

### Target SDK Version

The target SDK version simply says which API you can use methods from for your application.

> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. ... This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to `minSdkVersion`).
>
> -- [`<uses-sdk>` Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

### Example

As an example, let's say you use [`Display.getSize(Point)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)) in your app. This method only works on APIs 13+, so you *must* target 13 or higher. However, if you do not call this method on devices using APIs 12 or lower, you will not encounter any issues.

But, let's say your app requires that you have access to `Fragment`s and their methods (and don't want to use the support library). Then, you *must* have a minimum SDK level of 11--otherwise, it will crash on devices lower than that API level.

### Short answer

`android:minSdkVersion="8"` means your app can be used on Android 2.2+. `android: targetSdkVersion="16"` means you have access to anything from Android 4.1+ whenever you compile your app (but does *not* mean that older devices can use those features).

Answer (score 1):

minSdkVersion = 8 means that it will work on devices running Android 2.2 or later

Answer (score 1):

Eric's answer is very nice one.. I just wanna add few more things from the docs. It may help you..

**About minsdkversion**

1. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute
2. If you do not declare this attribute, the system assumes a default value of "1", which indicates that your application is compatible with all versions of Android
3. So If you use any api introduced after your minsdk version then the program will crash.

**About targetsdkversion**

1. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.
2. depending on your application's targetsdkversion on different version of android os the behavior and appearence might be change. Hence from the doc ..

> For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to
>   apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android
>   3.0 or higher and also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens (because support for API level 11 implicitly
>   supports larger screens).

For another example. say you set the targetsdk version as 5. Then in all os versions the menu, title bars and overall theme will be like ECLAIR. But if you set targetsdk version to 14. then for ics the theme will be ics. and on below version of os the theme will be corresponding to that os.

**Finally About maxsdkVersion:**

As the other two is mentioned so I think we should include this lonely attribute too. If this attribute is declared, its value must be equal to or greater than the system's API Level integer. If not declared, the system assumes that the application has no maximum API Level.